# Create dynamic elements in angularJs and use ng-model in best way

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, input

I want to create html input elements dynamically and get values from it.

Controller:

```
$scope.itemElements = [{
    "item": "item1",
}, {
    "item": "item2",
}, {
    "item": "item3",
}];
$scope.saveQuotation = function() {
    console.log($scope.itemElements);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="itemElemen in itemElements">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.item" placeholder="Enter item"/></td>
    </tr>
```

How can I get all values which are dynamically created and inputted.?

Comment: The array `$scope.itemElements` will have the updated values... so why can't you use that

Comment: How can I print individual values from `$scope.itemElements`

Comment: `angular.forEach($scope.itemElements, function (item, key) {
    console.log(item.name)
});`

Comment: getting undefined error..

Comment: ` console.log(item)`

Comment: above code should work as is.. to get the value.. its a javascript array.. so nothing to do with angular... get values as you get them for any other array

Comment: yes.. it was working,mistake was on the extracting data.